# настроить компилятор Delphi10.2Tokyo

Tags: delphi

[image: компилятор выкыдуе ошибку] помогите настроить компилятор Delphi10.2Tokyo

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

    Type
    Str25    = String[25];
        {}    List=^TBookRec; {Указатель на элемент типа TBookRec}{указатель                                         
 на следующий элемент}
      {  list_of_names = array[0..8] of string;}
    TBookRec = Record
                Title, Author, ISBN : Str25;{данные, хранимые в элементе}
{тип данных, который будет храниться в элементе стека}
                Price : Real;
                 Next : byte;
               End;
   Var
    BookRec : TBookRec;
    Next,p:integer;

begin
  try
{ TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    Next:=0;
           writeln(Next);
readln(BookRec.Title);{readln(myBookRec.Author,myBookRec.ISBN);}            
{myBookRec.Next:=myBookRec.Next+1; }
writeln(BookRec.Title);         writeln(' номер посследнего елемента списка         
 № ',BookRec.Next);
                       readln(BookRec.Author);
                        writeln(BookRec.Author);
                                                        writeln(BookRec.Title);
                           Next:=Next+1;
                                      writeln(Next); writeln(BookRec.Title);
                     //    read(p);      writeln(p);

                          except       on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: А какие проблемы с компилятором?

Comment: на скриншоте написана ошибка которую выкидует компилятор,

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в тело вопроса. По скриншоту ничего толком не найти.

Comment: вроде как тут https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2017/03/06/fix-delphi-error-msbuildtoolspath-is-not-specified-for-the-toolsversion/ что-то есть по теме

Comment: спасибо пишу другую программу, ошибка исчезла. )